# Do companions aim down sight or hip fire?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm going to start modding a gun for a companion soon, and I'm thinking about long barrels, stocks, etc. But then I realized that maybe they hip-fire all the time, and that would make the long barrel and stock pretty useless.

So do companions aim down sight or fire guns from their hip?

Comment: I was thinking we had already discussed this, but it looks like that was about whether VATS was hipfire or ADS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they ADS, and even if I'm wrong I got lots of materials so I could re-do the design, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable way to check this on consoles. Maybe if you were on PC you could check their damage somehow with the console.

Comment: Just note that companions use ammo if you give them a custom gun.  If you don't give them a gun, they have infinite ammo with their default weapon.  This factor alone makes it super annoying to refill their ammo, and they kind of suck to begin with.

Comment: @Nelson I'm using a sniper build, so I never use energy weapons because they can't be suppressed. I still find lots of fusion cells so I give them all to Nick Valentine, plus a nice energy weapon.

Answer (score 2):

Based on conflicting posts [here](http://www.gamesas.com/compansions-use-sights-hip-fire-both-t397504.html):

> I can see them raising the weapon up to aim, like your iron-sights do in third-person. So it would appear that they use sighted fire, almost exclusively.

and

> From what I have witnessed it is always hip fire.

it seems like they use **both**.

Additionally, a post [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/458604254460625118/):

> They can use both, same for settlers.

combined with a post [here](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/3858210-followers-aim-down-sights/):

> I think it just depends who you use. Nick valentine is a hip shooter, but piper seems to be able to scope,  who are you using?

supports this.

---

Note: I realize these are all forum posts, but from all 3 places, the consensus appears to be that they both *aim through the sights **and** fire from the hip*.

Comment: I would hope that they make this decision based on the range to their target.

Comment: @DCShannon it would definitely be ideal, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

It is noted on the wiki that they use vats but look like they are aiming in.

Comment: Could you link to the wiki and provide a quote?

Comment: Sadly the only  "Gaming site" I have that is not blocked is this one. My mom is a real Antigamer person

Comment: @LandonPoling Then how do you know what it notes on the wiki?

Comment: I saw it on the wiki before she blocked it.